# RETORNO DE VALOR DIGITADO COM JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, react, maps-javascript-api

Olá, eu precisava de uma ajuda. A ideia em JavaScript é a seguinte... O usuário digita um valor em um ***input***, e a aplicação **retorna **o valor correspondente a esse valor digita****, que já foi pré definido antes com constantes exemplo:

var '8' = 65.60
var '101' = 189
var '17' = 126

Quando o usuário digitar 8, a aplicação retorna 65.60, Quando o usuário digitar 101, a aplicação retorna 189, e assim por diante, alguém sabe como fazer algo assim?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acredito que seja algo do tipo :

```
var valorDigitado= document.getElementById(Id do campo do Input);

if(valorDigitado.value == 8){

var valor = 65.60;

}
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 0):

Você deve estar perguntando sobre **Switch**, que é comparada á cada cláusula e se a clausula for correspondida,o valor da sua variável for igual a um caso, ele retorna um valor pré determinado.

Para exemplificar melhor:

```
switch (expressão) {
  case valor1:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á valor1
    [break;]
  case valor2:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á valor2
    [break;]
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Instruções executadas quando o resultado da expressão for igual á valorN
    [break;]
  default:
    //Instruções executadas quando o valor da expressão é diferente de todos os cases
    [break;]
}
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda amigo, muito grato.